# Change css class definition for a document fragment

Tags: css

Is there a way to change an existing css class definition on a part - fragment of an html document while keeping the original class definition on the rest of the document? *I'm not interested to solutions adding additional css classes to differentiate the styles.*

For example in the following page ([jsbin demo here](http://jsbin.com/cofegirafe/edit?html,css,output)) I want to redefine the color of the .someClass css class to green on the text of the first paragraph and to red to the text of the second paragraph while use the default class definition on the third paragraph. Tried using the inline css with scoped attribute but it fails - it seems it's not meant for class definitions, the last someClass definition (red color) overrides all previous definitions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style scoped>
        .someClass { color: blue}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="first" >
    <style scoped>
        .someClass { color: green}
    </style>
    <p class="someClass">First paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="second" >
    <style scoped>
        .someClass { color: red}
    </style>
    <p class="someClass">Second paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="third" >
    <p class="someClass">Third paragraph</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Other than class definition, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp seems to notice that only Firefox supports the scope attribute. May be outdated though

Comment: Just a heads up - "document fragment" is actually a "thing": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment.... and some folks may wind up here after looking for help styling them. Any chance you could edit the original post ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a live Demo at the end of the page

https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Scoped styling seems to suffer cross browser support, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp however the jQuery example, gives a work around

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nikolas. I used jquery.scoped to overcome limited browser support for scoped css (works only in Firefox) . It worked for Chrome, IE6-11 but failed in MS Edge. I'll wait for a more complete answer for a while...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best approach would be to use the [`nth-of-type`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) selector. Thus you don't add extra css classes and it would work and it is totally supported by all actual browsers.

```css
 .someClass { color: blue}
div:nth-of-type(1) p { color: green; }
div:nth-of-type(2) p { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="first" >
    <p class="someClass">First paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="second" >
    <p class="someClass">Second paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="third" >
    <p class="someClass">Third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dez. Actually the example I posted was oversimplified. The real case is that I have about 20 css files with 1600 lines each with the same class names definitions. Tenths of class names from the css files are used in various parts (divs) of my page. I really don't  want to redefine the classes, I just want to use the class definitions from ccs file 1 in a part of my page, the class definitions from the css file 2 in another part of my page and etc. The best case would be scoped css but as I read from http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped its only supported in Firefox.

Comment: Sadly, you will need refactoring to achieve your goal. Any IDE or text editors and some tweaking will help you to do it fast.